# Selecting middle percentage of data from array

Tags: python, arrays, database, slice

I am trying to extract a selection of points from the centre of an array. Say the middle 20% (10% of points either side of the centre).

I am able to select the final and initial x% of data using array slicing. Is there also a way to find it at a given point somewhere along the array like the middle.

```
no_pts = round(len(data)*percent/100)

#change here to edit number of points
sample = pts[-no_pts:]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did it in the end. I'm not sure if there is a more concise way of doing it.

```
no_pts = round(len(data)*percent/100)

middle_point = round(len(data)/2)

sample = pts[middle_point-no_points/2 : middle_point + no_pts/2]
```

Comment: frankly, I think the simplest solutions like yours should be the first one to try to adopt if satisfactory. However,  (small caveat) I am not certain you are guaranteed to get the proper number of points, due to rounding error